# Monthly compound interest calculation using Python

Tags: python

```
# This program takes the original principal,
# calculates the annual interest rate 
# calculates the number of times the interest is compounded
# calculates how many years the account will earn interest
# and lastly displays the ending principal


# Input the original principal.

original_principal = int(input( 'Enter the starting principal: ' ))

# Input the annual interest rate.

annual_interest = float(input( 'Enter the annual interest rate: ' ))

# Input times per year the interest is compounded.

compound = int(input( 'How many times per year is the interest compounded? ' ))

# Input number of years account will earn interest.

total_years = int(input( 'For how many years will the account earn interest? ' ))

# Calculate ending principle amount after earning annual
# interest for a specified amount of years.

ending_principal = original_principal * (1 + annual_interest / compound) ** \
               (compound * annual_interest)

#Display the ending principle amount.

print ( 'At the end of 2 years you will have $' , \
    format(ending_principal, ',.2f'))
```

I use $1,000 as my original_principal (just as an example) and should get a desired ending_principal of $ 1, 051.22.

However I am nowhere near that number. 
My guess is I'm missing a parenthesis somewhere in the calculation.
I apologize in advance if I didn't format this code properly, this is my second time using stack overflow, still learning.

Comment: Maybe here: ```ending_principal = original_principal * ((1 + annual_interest / compound) ** (compound * annual_interest))```

Comment: Still comes out the same number

Comment: Are you trying to implement ```FV = PV * (1 + i) ** n``` compound interest formula?

Comment: You didn't use the `total_years` in your formula, so basically your formula is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fixed code. The intrest needs to be calculated as a decimal.

```
# This program takes the original principal,
# calculates the annual interest rate
# calculates the number of times the interest is compounded
# calculates how many years the account will earn interest
# and lastly displays the ending principal


# Input the original principal.

original_principal = int(input('Enter the starting principal: '))

# Input the annual interest rate.

annual_interest = float(input('Enter the annual interest rate (%): '))
annual_interest = annual_interest / 100

# Input times per year the interest is compounded.

compound = int(input('How many times per year is the interest compounded? '))

# Input number of years account will earn interest.

total_years = int(input('For how many years will the account earn interest? '))

# Calculate ending principle amount after earning annual
# interest for a specified amount of years.

ending_principal = (original_principal * (1 + annual_interest
                                      / compound) ** (compound * total_years)
                    )

# Display the ending principle amount.

print('At the end of ', total_years, 'years you will have $',
      format(ending_principal, '.2f'))
```

Comment: You formula is incorrect either. it should be `original_principal * (1 + annual_interest / compound) ** (total_years * compound)`